# How to put on the home path in an XML file as an environment variable?

Tags: xml, ros

I have a `.world` file in ROS for gazebo simulation which is an XML file.

How can I put on a dynamic home path instead of the static path in `<uri>` tag?

---

Here's my simplified `.world` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version='1.5'>
  <world name='default'>
    <visual name='base_link_visual_front_sonar'>
      <pose>0.109 0 0.209 0 -0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
      <mesh>
        <uri>/home/agn/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl</uri> <!--Note-->
      </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

---

How can I use `$HOME` instead of `/home/agn`?

I tried the following cases with the failed results:

```
<uri>~/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl</uri>
<uri>$HOME/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl</uri>
<uri>"$HOME/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl"</uri>
<uri>${HOME}/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl</uri>
<uri>"${HOME}/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl"</uri>
<uri>"${sys:user.home}/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl"</uri>
<uri>${sys:user.home}/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl</uri>
<uri>${user.home}/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl</uri>
<uri>"${user.home}/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl"</uri>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components) Gazebo allows to find additional models at paths that are listed listed on the environment variable `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`.

Adding a path to an environment variable is well described in [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) and can be done like

```
PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/your/path/to/check
```

Now you are able to set the uri like

```
<uri>model://relative/path/file.stl</uri>
```

Note that there is also [a hacks](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6416/using_a_urdf_in_gazebo-package-uris-not-described/?answer=6419#post-id-6419) which allows changing the environment variable in the *package.xml*.

Comment: Can you explain more for in my case in `<uri>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

According to [roslaunch wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML),you should try this:

```
<uri>$(env HOME)/catkin_ws/src/description/meshes/sonar.stl</uri>
```

Comment: It doesn't work: `[Error]: Failed to load joints for transmission`